# How can I get sub_level indexes of a higher level index in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have been working on a Pandas Dataframe, and I had an issue retrieving the sub_level indexes of a higher level index.

This image shows my Dataframe structure:

[image: This image shows my Dataframe structure]

For example, in the picture above, I would like to retrieve the "DCSID" indexes that only exist for the "Equipment+Label" key '-444/0', which are '-111111', '-222222' and '-333333'.

I thought about using ***df.loc['-444/0'].index.levels[0]*** since ***df.loc['-444/0']*** returns the sub dataframe of the key '-444/0', and use  ***index.levels[0]*** to retrieve the result that I want later.

This is the result of doing ***df.loc['-444/0']***:

[image: This is the result of doing ***df.loc['-444/0']***]

It didn't work, which is not *logical*, because I thought that ***df.loc['-444/0']*** returns a NEW dataframe.

Anyway, I found out that ***df.index.levels[1]*** is equivalent to ***df.iloc['-444/0'].index.levels[0]*** both returning the list of all the indexes in "DCSID":

> Int64Index([-444444, -333333, -305500, -304445, -301064, -300015, -299069,
>               -297188, -296241, -295295,
>               ...
>                -17132,  -15622,  -14112,  -12602,   -9596,   -8086,   -6576,
>                 -5066,   -2060,    -542],
>              dtype='int64', name='DCSID', length=120)

This is a part of my code:

```py
for i in df.index.levels[0]: #Choose from first level
    for j in df.loc[i].index.levels[0]: #Choose from second level going through the i-th first level
        for k in df.loc[i, j, slice(None)].index: #Choose from third level going through the j-th second level
            #Code here
```

Comment: Please provide sample data

Comment: Here is a data sample:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NnVBOz-JVdVM870f3UryXtggHGw585l4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MultiIndex are strange animals. If you really want to extract value from them, start with a `reset_index`:

```
df.loc['-444/0'].reset_index()['DCSID'].unique()
```

should give the expected result `array([-111111, -222222, -333333, -444444], dtype=int64)`

Answer (score 1):

I am using your csv file columns you can change the column name according to your requirement

Apply filter using get_values and provide DSCID or equipmentKey in isin list

```
df = df[(df.index.get_level_values('EquipmentKey').isin(['-444']))]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
unique_dscid = df['DSCID'].unique()
```

Second way :

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df[(df['EquipmentKey']=='-444')]
unique_dscid =df['DSCID'].unique()
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I appreciate it.

Comment: @MohamedAzizTousli you welcome and give up vote if you find it useful.

Comment: I can't. :/. It says: 
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @MohamedAzizTousli No problem